# use gradle to publish both jar and bootJar

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, jar, publish

Here is sample project information, using spring boot framework.

group id : com.test
artifact id: sample
version: 1.0.0

I'd like to publish both jar and bootJar to my maven repository.

jar: **sample-1.0.0.jar**
bootJar: **sample_starter-1.0.0.jar**

sample_starter-1.0.0.jar is for internal use to create docker container running on my linux server while sample-1.0.0.jar will be archived as one of my asserts.

But I got sample_starter-1.0.0.jar and sample-1.0.0-plain.jar. Is there any way to make the jar version produced without the **plain** classifier? I tried customizing the jar task with setting **classifier=''** but it did not work at all.

Here is my build.gradle settings.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

group='com.test'
version='1.0.0'

publishing {
    publications {
        plainJar(MavenPublication) {
            artifact jar
        }
        starterJar(MavenPublication) {
            artifact bootJar {
                artifactId = "${project.name}_starter"
            }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            name = 'myRepo'
            url = layout.buildDirectory.dir("myRepo")
        }
    }
}
```

[publish result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEul1.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is documented in the Spring Boot Gradle plugin docs. The reason for the `plain` classifier is because both the regular/plain JAR and the Spring boot fat/uber JAR have the same name. So, this would lead to the tasks that output each respective artifact overwriting each other or causing errors in general. To remove the `plain` classifier, per the documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging-executable.and-plain-archives

```
tasks.named<BootJar>("bootJar") {
    archiveClassifier.set("boot") // or whatever classifier you want
}

tasks.named<Jar>("jar") {
    archiveClassifier.set("")
}
```